# Why does the "right" value contain the "successful" outcome with Eithers?

Tags: functional-programming, conventions

In functional programming languages such as Scala and Haskell, there is an `Either` type that is often used to represent a successful result *or* a failure/error object. An either is said to be 'left' when it contains a failure and to be 'right' when it contains a successful result.

Is there a reason why "unsuccessful" is "left" and "successful" is "right"? Why are these directions used in the first place?

Comment: For one, you get the happy scenario sugar: `if outcome.isRight` :) In which case I guess `left` should have been called `wrong` ...

Comment: If you have to pick one, having "Right" represent the right (as in "not-wrong") result makes sense. I suspect many programmers have created an isomorphic type that has `Success` and `Failure` and then realised that it's a "bright idea" that quickly creates a mess. I know I have.

Answer (score 1):

From Haskell's [Data. Either](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html) documentation:

The Left constructor is used to hold an      error value and the Right constructor is used to hold a correct value (mnemonic: "right" also means "correct").

Comment: Although that is a nice reference, I find it somewhat unconvincing that it's all down to a mnemonic. It could still be a coincidence the terminology sort of fits the use of directions. Can anyone supply references to the origin of this construct?

Comment: My first instinct was to think that it is a historical accident, so it makes sense to me that the mnemonic came after, but that's just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but in Haskell `Either` is monadic on its second type, which is the type associated with the `Right` constructor. Generic monadic code will therefore change only the right type, so the left type which remains constant is used to hold the error.

So the main reason would be that swapping the type arguments to `Either` so that `Either a b` is `Left b` or `Right a` is annoying to read for no real benefit.

Comment: It's also not possible to have the `Monad` instance work on the left type argument in the way that it works on the right type argument because of the way Haskell type partial application works (likewise for `Functor` and `Applicative`). There's no type-level equivalent to `flip` that would allow this to happen since even with `TypeSynonymInstances` enabled, all type synonyms must be fully applied if they are used in an instance declaration. I think this is disallowed because it would otherwise make type inference impossible in certain cases.